# Django Custom middleware don't display message in each page

Tags: django, middleware

I am trying to print a add like message using session in each page while user visit my page.
And i came out with this code it display my marketing message in index.html.

middleware.py---

```
from .models import MarketingMessage
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisplayMarketing(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def process_request(self, request):
        print("something")
        try:
            request.session['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session['marketing_message']  = False
```

my views.py--

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
    context = {'products':products,'marketing_message':marketing_message}
    return render(request,'pro/index.html',context)
```

models.py--

```
from django.db import models


class MarketingMessage(models.Model):

    message = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False,null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False,null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.message[:12])
```

base.html--

```
{% if marketing_message %}
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible alert-top-message" role="alert">
        <h3>
          {{ request.session.marketing_message|safe }}
        </h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can be improved in your code. Let's go in parts:

1.

```
marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
```

This will raise an `IndexError` if there are no entries in your database. Even though I find weird why would you want to query like that, you could do `MarketingMessage.objects.first()` instead which will return None if no entries are found.

2.

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
    context = {'products':products,'marketing_message':marketing_message}
    return render(request,'pro/index.html',context)
```

Why are you redoing the same query you did in the middleware? There is no point in do that if you already implemented there. Remember that middleware hooks are called in every request/response so everything you process there should not be reprocessed in the views.

3.

```
def process_request(self, request):
        print("something")
        try:
            request.session['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session['marketing_message']  = False
```

`process_request` hook is called on each request. In your case you want a hook to be called when processing the response. You can use [process_template_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) for that purpose. And there is no point in writing it in the session object since you are processing it again after every request.